# How to create correct 2D movement in C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently using rigidbody.velocity in the Update() method to move my player character. That method unfortunately causes problems, as I can't influence my character using addForce, and I was told updating the velocity every frame is a mistake. Is there a correct way to manage movement in Unity ?

```
theRB.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * playerSpeed;
```

Comment: It depends what u want to achieve, out of my 5 games only 1 uses physics based movement, you can move your character by just vectors gradually overtime

Comment: @Menyus By that do you mean using a loop inside a IEnumerator ?

Comment: @Nao I'm not familiar with "loop inside a IEnumerator" technique, but it sounds ill-advised on the surface.  Menyus is most likely referring to updating the velocity/position/rotation of an object in MonoBehavior.Update.  Here is a simple tutorial (not mine, I just found it by searching).  https://www.noob-programmer.com/unity3d/basic-movement-in-unity3d/